# If $f^{-1}(U)$ is empty, then $(f_{\ast}\mathcal O_Y)_p = 0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I just wanted to do a sanity check real quick.  Let's say I have a continuous function $f: Y \rightarrow X$, with $\mathcal O_Y$ a sheaf of rings on $Y$.  Suppose for some $p \in X$, I look at the stalk at $p$ of the direct image $$(f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y)_p = \varinjlim\limits_{U \ni p} \mathcal O_Y(f^{-1}U)$$  If there exists an open neighborhood $U_0$ of $p$ such that $f^{-1}U_0$ is empty, can I conclude that the stalk is the zero ring?  I know that $\mathcal O_Y(\emptyset)$ is the zero ring.  If $(s,V)$ is any element of $ (f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y)_p$ (where $V$ is an open neighborhood of $p$, and $s \in f_{\ast} \mathcal O_Y(V) = \mathcal O_Y(f^{-1}V)$), then $V \cap U_0$ is an open neighborhood of $p$ which is contained in $U_0$, hence $f^{-1}(V \cap U_0) = \emptyset$, and so $$(s,V) = (s_{|V \cap U_0},V \cap U_0) = 0$$ Is this right?

Comment: I think so, yes. As you point out, for any germ $(s,V)$ at $p$ you can pick a representative with open set contained in $U_0$. But such a representative is necessarily equal to the zero section. I'm a novice at AG though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(f_\ast \mathcal{O}_Y)_p$, being a direct limit, admits a morphism $\mathcal{O}_Y (f^{-1}U)\to (f_\ast \mathcal{O}_Y)_p$.

If $f^{-1}U = \emptyset$, then $\mathcal{O}_Y (f^{-1}U)$ is the zero ring, which means that $(f_\ast \mathcal{O}_Y)_p$ must also be the zero ring.

Comment: That's a good way to think about it, thanks.  Ring homomorphisms here have to send the identity to the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Being a direct limit over restriction, then you can think about it this way: once you have an open set where it is empty, then any smaller open set will remain empty.

Namely, if $V \subseteq U$ then $f^{-1} (V) \subseteq f^{-1} (U)$.

It seems you identified this in your proof already, which seems fine to me. When you remember it for future reference, it's probably easier to remember it as I described it instead of trying to write up a formal proof each time you need to use it.